# FileInputStream unmarshalling, but HttpInputStream won't in Java

Tags: java

I can marhsall XML from a file when I read it from disk, but when I download it via the web I get this error.

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException
```

I assume the web input stream contains additional information or something?

**Works**

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Doesnt Work**

```
InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

BulkDataRecordType bulkDataRecordType = getObjectFromXml(inputStream);
```

In another class

```
public BulkDataRecordType getObjectFromXml(InputStream inputStream)
        {

            try {

                    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BulkDataRecordType.class);
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
                    bulkDataRecordType = (BulkDataRecordType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);

                } catch (JAXBException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: First port of call: stop wrapping every single method call in a separate exception handler. It makes it much harder to read the code, and means you'll try to keep going even in the face of failure, which I suspect you don't want.

Comment: Have you made sure the stream from the url contains anything? Premature end of file is saying you have nothing left to read.

Comment: Sorry, I will refactor that stuff once I get it working.

Comment: Yes I used a InputStreamReader and BufferedReader to read the contents to a string and its there.

Comment: other than the fact that you are potentially ignoring exceptions, your code is largely correct.  i'm guessing that your url stream has the wrong data in it.

Comment: did you read the xml stream before trying to parse it?

Comment: Is it valid xml, basically?

Comment: Has to be valid XML, if I can read from disk just fine and marshall it from there.  Same file, just one is being read over the web.

Comment: You might want to check that the web version of your XML for validity, just to be sure. You can use an online tool like [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

Comment: No errors when I copied and pasted.  Its on my localhost so I couldnt test the URL version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am first checking the checksum of the string.  Once I commented this out it worked.  I found a solution to create two new streams and it worked.  If you have a better solution let me know.

```
public byte[] getCheckSumFromFile(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        MessageDigest md = null;

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        InputStream is = null;

        try {
          is = new DigestInputStream(inputStream, md);
        }
        finally {
              try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        return md.digest();
    }
```

**Create Two Streams From Original**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1 ) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

        // Get check sum of downloaded file
        byte[] fileCheckSum = getCheckSumFromFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: You are using an inputStream so try marking the stream before you digest it (that will need to read it to calculate the digest), then reset if you want to reread the content.  So: Mark; Digest; Reset; Read.

Comment: I dont believe it supports mark/read. java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported